# Delphi: ARC and Objective-C wrapped objects - how to release?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delphi, automatic-ref-counting, firemonkey

In Delphi/FMX there is no ARC for the Objective-C objects represented by the import wrapper classes and interfaces.

> When dealing with Objective-C objects you’ll have to call retain and
>   release yourself at the correct points. Allocating a new Objective-C
>   object will initialize its reference count to 1 and calling release
>   will drop it to 0 thus destroying it.
>   http://ridingdelphi.blogspot.de/2014/01/the-quest-to-migrate-ios-squarecam-app_3169.html

For example, i want to create a UILabel dynamically. According to the reference above, my code should be look like this (I'm assuming that I have chosen the positions for retail and release correctly):

```
    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
      lbl: UILabel;
    begin
      lbl := TUILabel.Wrap(TUILabel.alloc.init);
      lbl.retain;
      ...
      lbl.release;
    end;
```

It does not work. What is the right way to release wrapped Objective-C objects in Delphi/FMX?

With "It doesn't works" I mean that the UILabel is not released as expected ans still allocates the memory. I found this with the help of the Xcode Allocation Instrument.

Comment: With "It doesn't works" I mean that the UILabel is not released as expected ans still allocates the memory. I found this with the help of the Xcode Allocation Instrument.

Comment: @TomBrunberg Of course, I've already tried all this. The object simply stucks in the memory.

Comment: OK, Hopefully somebody with better knowledge in `iOC` will answer soon. Btw, you can delete irrelevant comments with the delete button right after the end of your comment (becomes visible when you hover your comment).

Comment: How about a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

`TUILabel.alloc.init` increases the reference count by one. After your call to `retain` you have a reference count of two. But then you release the object only once.

So you either have to call `release` twice:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  lbl: UILabel;
begin
  lbl := TUILabel.Wrap(TUILabel.alloc.init);
  lbl.retain;
  ...
  lbl.release;
  lbl.release;
end;
```

Or remove the call to `retain`:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  lbl: UILabel;
begin
  lbl := TUILabel.Wrap(TUILabel.alloc.init);
  ...
  lbl.release;
end;
```